# To start Kafka consumer and an HTTP server in parallel?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

Is there a way to start the go-server and kafka consumer parallely efficiently.
What i am doing is below ?

```
go consumers.KafkaConsumer()
router := router.NewRouter()
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8001", router))
```

Is this the correct way or are there any other way to do the same ?

Comment: `Is this the correct way`: it depends of your requirements/program intrinsic. `are there any other way to do the same ?` a million different ways, all as good as each other given the current description of your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is correct. If there is a chance `consumers.KafkaConsumer` could terminate with an error, you might want to handle that:

```
go func() {
  log.Fatal(consumers.KafkaConsumer())
}()
```

If not, then what you have is sufficient.